# Using the Rally API to create a new defect using PHP and curl

Tags: rally

I'm using PHP and curl and trying to create a defect in Rally.

```
<?php
define('XML_POST_URL', 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/defect/create');

/**
 * Initialize handle and set options
 */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, XML_POST_URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, '[USERNAME]:[PASSWORD]');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '<Defect> <Description>blah blah blah</Description> <Name>my defect</Name> <Priority>None</Priority> <ReleaseNote>false</ReleaseNote> <Severity>Major Problem</Severity> <State>Open</State> <Owner ref=\"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/user/[USERID]\"/> </Defect>');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

/**
 * Check for errors
 */
if ( curl_errno($ch) ) {
    $result = 'cURL ERROR -> ' . curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch);
    echo "ERROR! " . $result;
} else {
    $returnCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    switch($returnCode){
        case 200:
            break;
        default:
            $result = 'HTTP ERROR -> ' . $returnCode;
            break;
    }
}

curl_close($ch);

$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();

xml_parse($xml_parser, $result);
$returnXML = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
echo "<br>" . $returnXML->asXML();
```

?>

When trying to print out the returnXML, I get the following error:

> Cannot parse input stream as XML document: Error on line 1: Open quote
>   is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "ref".

When I do a print_r, I see this:

> SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [rallyAPIMajor] => 1 [rallyAPIMinor] => 29 ) [Errors] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [OperationResultError] => Cannot parse input stream as XML document: Error on line 1: Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "ref". ) [Warnings] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )

I'm expecting to see an  similar to this example: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/rest_xml.jsp

The error message sounds like there's something wrong with the ref, which is part of the .  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the  from `"<Owner ref=\"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/user/[USERID]\"/>`

to

```
<Owner user/[USERID]/>
```

and that seemed to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You have an unneeded slash before the double quote characters in the "Owner" element's "ref" attribute.

```
<Owner ref=\"https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/user/[USERID]\"...
```

Should be:

```
<Owner ref="https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/user/[USERID]"...
```